# How to make bottom sheet above maps activity?

Tags: android

I would like to make my activity like Google Maps.

I have added a bottom sheet but, when I run the application the bottom sheet appeared below the maps while other activities appear above it without any problem.

How to make it appear above the map [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJpwY.png)?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

```
<!-- Bottom Sheet Content -->
<include layout="@layout/content_bottom_sheet" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use below code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >



    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/texi_white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Map"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/food_white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="List"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

`

Comment: Thanks for the answer , not button but material design-BottomSheet

Comment: Yes but you can use your control instead of